# Data bytes to sockaddr conversion in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift3, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I am converting `Data bytes` to `sockaddr` for getting `sa_family_t`

In `ObjC`, it is as below:

```
NSData *     hostAddress;
- (sa_family_t)hostAddressFamily {
    sa_family_t     result;

    result = AF_UNSPEC;
    if ( (self.hostAddress != nil) && (self.hostAddress.length >= sizeof(struct sockaddr)) ) {
        result = ((const struct sockaddr *) self.hostAddress.bytes)->sa_family;
    }
    return result;
}
```

In swift I am trying to convert it as below:

```
var hostAddress:Data?

 private func hostAddressFamily() -> sa_family_t{

        var result: sa_family_t = sa_family_t(AF_UNSPEC)
        if (hostAddress != nil) && ((hostAddress?.count ?? 0) >= MemoryLayout<sockaddr>.size) {

            // Generic parameter 'ContentType' could not be inferred
            self.hostAddress!.withUnsafeBytes({ bytes in
                bytes.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1, {sockBytes in
                    result = sockBytes.pointee.sa_family
                })
            })
        }

        return result
    }
```

`Getting error :  Generic parameter ‘ContentType’ could not be inferred`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the signature of `Data.withUnsafeBytesType`:

```
func withUnsafeBytes<ResultType, ContentType>(_ body: (Swift.UnsafePointer<ContentType>) throws -> ResultType) rethrows -> ResultType
```

This method is generic over `ResultType` and `ContentType`, and the `ContentType` is used in the argument of the closure body.

What compiler is trying to say is that it does not know what type `bytes` is of. Generally, to fix this type of errors, you'll want to annotate the type in the closure:

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { (_ bytes: UnsafePointer<...>) -> Void in ... }
```

Also, it's unlikely you'll need to bind the memory twice since `NSData` is untyped, and you already specifying a type to bind it to.

---

Putting it all together:

```
func hostAddressFamily() -> sa_family_t {

  var result = sa_family_t(AF_UNSPEC)

  guard
    let hostAddress = hostAddress,
    hostAddress.count >= MemoryLayout<sockaddr>.size
  else {
    return result
  }

  hostAddress.withUnsafeBytes { (_ bytes: UnsafePointer<sockaddr>) in
    result = bytes.pointee.sa_family
  }

  return result
}
```